# Find our versions of ALL dependencies installed by Carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, dependency-management, carthage

How to know which versions of dependencies do I have installed via Carthage?

Cartfile.resolved does inform only about the dependencies of my project but not about dependencies of dependency of my project..?

Comment: So you have dependencies on your project which also has dependencies themselves ? Have you tried checking each of the projects ? as dependencies are managed separately by each project.

Comment: @CoderPug In case of Cocoapods they would be visible in podspec of given framework. In case of Carthage where's the list what to install with given framework..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone is still wondering:

`Cartfile.resolved`